# Why does the ES6 module import expression not work for json files in assets folder with some path arguments?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, import, es6-modules

I encountered an ES6 import situation that appears to be not logical and I wonder why the following import does not work within methods of a Vue.js SFC:

```js
const fullContentFile = '@/assets/rules/rules.json'
import(fullContentFile).then(data => console.log('data 8: ', data))
```

It throws the following error on the browser's console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/rules/rules.json'
    at eval (eval at ./src/components/staboqwi lazy recursive (app.js:2117), <anonymous>:5:11)
```

My project setup to reproduce that failure:

1. `vue create import-issue` (create a Vue.js project and accept the defaults)
2. create a file: `src/assets/rules/rules.json` with the following content:

```js
    [1,2,3,4,5]
```

3. In App.vue add the following `created()`method:

```js
created() {
  // The first three imports work always:
  import('@/assets/rules/rules.json').then(data =>
    console.log('data 1: ', data)
  )
  
  const file = 'rules'
  import('@/assets/rules/' + file + '.json').then(data =>
    console.log('data 2: ', data)
  )

  const fileName = 'rules.json'
  import('@/assets/rules/' + fileName).then(data =>
    console.log('data 3: ', data)
  )

  // The next two imports break compilation if used within htmlcars project
  const fileName2 = 'rules/rules.json'
  import('@/assets/' + fileName2).then(data =>
    console.log('data 4: ', data)
  )

  const fileName3 = 'assets/rules/rules.json'
  import('@/' + fileName3).then(data => console.log('data 5: ', data))

  // Those imports don't work:
  const contentFile = '/assets/rules/' + file + '.json'
  import('@' + contentFile).then(data => console.log('data 6: ', data))

  const atContentFile = '@/assets/rules/' + file + '.json'
  import(atContentFile).then(data => console.log('data 7: ', data))

  const fullContentFile = '@/assets/rules/rules.json'
  import(fullContentFile).then(data => console.log('data 8: ', data))
},
```

As you can see from the variants of imports the only difference is what's provided to the path argument as String and what is stored in a const/variable.

I did spent 2 nights trying to find an answer on Google and stackoverflow. Maybe someone with more javascript background than I have can explain what's wrong with the last three imports compared to the ones before.

An interesting side effect is, that the 4th and 5th import break compilation of the [htmlcars](https://github.com/Xiphoseer/htmlcars) project, if that `create()` method is added to its `App.vue` file (don't forget to add the `src/assets/rules/rules.json`). If commented out the project will build. Why is that? The imports are totally unrelated to the scss files that fail to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be aware of the fact that `import()` statements in today's common JS project (including Vue) are processed by Webpack at **build time, not just at runtime**

At build time Webpack needs to know which file is imported so it can make it available for consumption at runtime (transpile JS, pre-process SCSS etc). But because this import is dynamic and Webpack cannot execute your code, it can not possibly know what the argument passed into `import()` **exactly means**. It can only parse the code and make a *guess* - "Which file can be imported here?" (based on the content of your file system)

So it makes no sense to look at the examples and compare the cases from "JavaScript execution" point of view because what works and what does not ultimately depends on Webpack's ability to parse the expression inside `()` and make a correct guess...

More on this in Webpack's docs - [Dynamic expressions in import()](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)

Comment: Thank for that link. It helped to understand the issue better. By providing "String context" with some path info at build time Webpack gets an opportunity to guess where to find the module. The whole argument with the variable is evaluated at runtime and that doesn't work when too much of the first parts of a path are hidden from Webpack.

Why imports 3 and 4 break compilation of scss code still remains unanswered.

Comment: Well I don't have a time to recreate your whole project but my guess why 4. and 5. break the compilation is because they include too much (including SCSS) as dynamically loaded modules and at the same time you probably import SCSS statically so that creates conflict Webpack is unable resolve. Does it matter really ? Those imports are simply wrong anyway...